# how to Fetch Url one by one dynamically in selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to selenium Python. I want to search a keyword on google and open it and on the results section i want to click first url and fetch data and go back click second link and fetch data.....and so on till 10 URLs. i have done it using x-path in the below code but i want to do it dynamically without writing specific x-path of one link?
P.S - i have tried using for loop but i am not able to do it.
to sum it all i want to get the results of below code without specifying certain x-path but fetch url dynamically for any keyword.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="E:\Sahil\selenium\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

print(driver.title)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@name='btnK']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
# time.sleep(5)

# 1>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium Web Driver").click()

a=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in a:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 2>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "The Selenium Browser Automation Project :: Documentation ...").click()

b=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in b:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 3>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium Tutorial for Beginners: Learn WebDriver in 7 Days").click()

c=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in c:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 4>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium with Python — Selenium Python Bindings 2 ...").click()

d=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in d:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 5>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium: Definition, How it works and Why you need it ...").click()

e=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in e:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 6>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "selenium · PyPI").click()

f=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in f:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 7>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium (software) - Wikipedia").click()

g=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in g:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 8>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium: Health benefits, sources, and potential risks").click()

h=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in h:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# 9>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "SeleniumHQ/selenium: A browser automation ... - GitHub").click()

i=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
for data in i:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()

# Next Page
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "2").click()

# 10>>>
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Selenium - Testing Framework | Sauce Labs").click()
j=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")

for data in j:
    print(data.text)
driver.back()
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

print(driver.title)

driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']").send_keys('selenium')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='FPdoLc tfB0Bf']//input[@name='btnK']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='r']/a") 
links = []
for x in a:      # this loop get all the webpages link and store into 'links' list.
    links.append(x.get_attribute('href'))
link_data = []
for new_url in links:    #go on every webpage and store page source in link_data list.
    print('new url : ' , new_url)
    driver.get(new_url)
    link_data.append(driver.page_source)
    driver.back()

#print('link data len : ' ,len(link_data)) 
#print('link data [0] : ' , link_data[0])  # print first webpage source.
```

this code get all data from all the link and save in `link_data` list.

For p tag you can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
page = bs(link_data[0],'html.parser')
p_tag = page.find_all('p')
print(p_tag)
```

Comment: It is working Fine But it is not getting the content from all the webpages opened. For instance i want content of p tag <p> of the urls opened. this code is capturing the url name and storing in new_url and displaying the same. i want the data of p tag <p> to be displayed of the websites opened not the url name.   EDIT : i had got the data in p tag using : a = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
           for data in a:
           print(data.text).                 Thanks for the above code. And also can you explain the above code like between array and for loop . what each line does??

Comment: uncomment last two line, which store all the content from all the webpages opened.

Comment: Thanks mate. And also if we want to get content of a specified tag as i mentioned earlier like <p> p tag. or any other what do we need to do? link in this code we are fetching the page source .i want the data written in the web page for eg articles.

Comment: Also i have few question i want to ask should i ask here only?

Comment: tell me where do you want to talk.